# How to build a simple image gallery in JavaScript using popup window

Tags: javascript, gallery, popupwindow

I have looked all over the internet for help but I can't get it to work!

Would someone be able to give me an example of how to code something like this?

I would resize an image, and have a thumbnail size image and a bigger one for the popup. I want an user to click on the thumbnail size image and have the full size image in a popup.

I am very much a beginner to Javascript, I think that the code would involve an window.open and an onclick function but besides that I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **Image gallery in 9 lines of JavaScript.**

All you have to do - create two directories, one for `images` and one for `thumbnails`; the `thumbnails` directory should be placed within the `images` directory. Image name should be the same. Use the `alt` attribute for an image description and finally, feel free to change CSS values.

```
// HTML
<ul id="gallery">
    <li><img src="images/thumbnails/img-01.jpg" alt="desc-01"></li>
    <li><img src="images/thumbnails/img-02.jpg" alt="desc-02"></li>
    <li><img src="images/thumbnails/img-03.jpg" alt="desc-03"></li>
    <li><img src="images/thumbnails/img-04.jpg" alt="desc-04"></li>
</ul>

// CSS
#gallery {
    list-style-type:none; background-color: #f0f0f0; overflow: hidden; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;
}

#gallery li {
    background-color: #fff; float: left; margin: 5px; padding: 5px;
}

#gallery li img {
    width: 120px; height: 120px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;
}

//
// Image gallery in 9 lines of JavaScript
// http://stackoverflow.com/users/1310701/hex494d49
//
window.onload = function() {
    var img = document.getElementById("gallery").getElementsByTagName("IMG"), w, i;
    for (i = 0; i < img.length; i++){
        (function(i){
            img[i].onclick = function() {
                w = window.open("","gallery","menubar=0,scrollbars=0");
                w.document.write("<img src='" + img[i].src.replace(/thumbnails\//,'') + "' alt='" + img[i].alt + "' /><div>" + img[i].alt + "</div>");
            };
        }(i));
    }
};
```

### **Image gallery in 15 lines of JavaScript.**

```
// HTML
// The same as above

// CSS
// The same as above
// 

// Image gallry in 15 lines of Javascript
// http://stackoverflow.com/users/1310701/hex494d49
//
window.onload = function() {
    var img = document.getElementById("gallery").getElementsByTagName("IMG"), w, i;
    for (i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
        (function(i) {
            img[i].onclick = function() {
                if (!w || w.closed) {
                    w = window.open("","gallery","menubar=0,scrollbars=0");
                    w.document.write("<img src='" + img[i].src.replace(/thumbnails\//,'') + "' alt='' /><div>" + img[i].alt + "</div>");
                } else {
                    w.document.getElementsByTagName('IMG')[0].src = img[i].src.replace(/thumbnails\//,'');      
                    w.document.getElementsByTagName('DIV')[0].innerHTML = img[i].alt;
                }
                w.focus();
            };
        }(i));
    }
};
```

Check the [first](http://jsbin.com/vomixegi/1/edit) or the [second](http://jsbin.com/vomixegi/3/edit) working version.

Comment: Thank you! How would I get the thumbnail and bigger image to be associated with each other? How does the computer know to pair which thumbnail to which image? Right now the thumbnail and CSS works, but I can't click on the image.

Comment: @Petunia Use the same name, and that's fine 'cause you're using different directories. So, `images/thumbnails/img-01.jpg` is a thumbnail of this one `images/img-01.jpg`. I think that's the best approach, but you may name them in a differnet way; you may add an extension to the thumbnail, like `/images/thumbnails/img-small.jpg` or `/images/thumbnails/img-120-120.jpg`... but if you want to use different names this part `img[i].src.replace(/thumbnails\//,'')` should be modified. This `img[i].src.replace(/thumbnails\//,'')` says - replace `thumbails/` from the src of an image.

Comment: @Petunia Check the updated answer, I added another version of JavaScript