# Jquery: Show/Hide Div broken

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-listener

**Scenario:** I'm trying to create a script that allows a user to click a thumbnail image and display a larger image in preview box. I'm using a div and a img for this example just as a placeholder for now.

**Question** In Jquery, is there a way to use a function with parameters as a callback for a onclick event listener? I've looked at `addEventListener` and `Onclick` and `.on` method in jquery, but nothing seems to fit what i'm searching for.

**My Attempts:**

1. http://jsfiddle.net/davideugenepeterson/9emhuzw0/3/
2. http://jsfiddle.net/EhtrR/931/

**Javascript:**

```
var numberOfImages = 4;
var imageArray = [];

//since i'm going to hide all other divs each time a img is clicked,
// I need to be calling from imageArray[] so I can difArray check later
for (i = 0; i <= numberOfImages; i++) {
    //counting starts from zero, but frontend already built their naming convention to start with 1
    if (i === 0) {
        continue
    }
    imageArray.push(i);
}

for (i = 0; i <= imageArray.length; i++) {
    if (i === 0) {
        continue
    }  
    //on each img click show corresponding div and hide all others, not working
    $("#img-" + imageArray[i]).on('click', function () {
        $("#div-" + i).show();
    });
}
```

Comment: I took a look at your code and I think your approach is a bit complicated. You may have hundreds of images but you don't need to make an extra array; furthermore, you don't have to use jQuery (only) for this task. I'm saying this since you asked in your initial question. In the other hand, you can build the DIV element(s) in the fly, of course, having in mind what's inside it. I can add that solution if you'd like to use it.

Comment: Oh, I see you edited the question again ;) If I knew that you need a image gallery I would already be done :) Check this answer [How to build a simple image gallery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24522439/how-to-build-a-simple-image-gallery-in-javascipt-using-popup-window) first and if you find it useful, I could go further and modify it to use a DIV instead of a popup window

Comment: Any idea if there's an approach to this in Jquery without having to use `data-number`? Similar to @hex494D49 answer?

Comment: Check the updated answer below, I added jQuery version as well

Comment: If it helps anyone in the future, here is what I ended up using as per @hex494D49 answer: http://jsfiddle.net/davideugenepeterson/z1zfrgjk/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution (four variations)

a)

```
// JavaScript
var img = document.getElementsByTagName('IMG'),
    div= document.getElementsByTagName('DIV'), 
    current, i;

for(i = 0; i < img.length; i++){
  (function(i){ 
    img[i].onclick = function(){
      div[i].style.display = 'block';
      if(current) current.style.display = 'none';
      current = div[i]; 
    };
  })(i);
}
```

b)

```
var img = document.getElementsByTagName('IMG'),
    div= document.getElementsByTagName('DIV'), 
    current, i;

for(i = 0; i < img.length; i++){
    (function(i){
      img[i].onclick = function() { callback(i); };
    })(i); 
}

function callback(i){
  div[i].style.display = 'block';
  if(current) current.style.display = 'none';
  current = div[i];   
}
```

c)

```
var img = document.getElementsByTagName('IMG'),
    div= document.getElementsByTagName('DIV'), 
    current, i;

for(i = 0; i < img.length; i++){
      img[i].onclick = callback.call(this,i);
}

function callback(i){
  return function () {
    div[i].style.display = 'block';
    if(current) current.style.display = 'none';
    current = div[i];   
  };  
}
```

---

```
<!-- HTML -->

<style>
  div {display:none;}
</style>

<img src="01.jpg" alt="" />
<img src="02.jpg" alt="" />
<img src="03.jpg" alt="" />
<img src="04.jpg" alt="" />
<img src="05.jpg" alt="" />

<div>first</div>
<div>second</div>
<div>third</div>
<div>fourth</div>    
<div>fifth</div>
```

Working [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/fatexopupota/1/edit?html,js,output)

d) jQuery version

```
(function(){
  var div = $('div'), current;
  $('img').each(function(index){
    $(this).bind ('click', function(){
      $('div:nth(' + index + ')').show();
      if(current) current.hide();
      current = $('div:nth(' + index + ')');
    });
  });
})();
```

Working [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/pawaxuhufili/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Code not working? http://jsbin.com/pawaxuhufili/1/edit?html,js,output this is almost exactly what i'm looking for.

Comment: @DavidEugenePeterson Not sure what's not working. All the code above works just fine. Or maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Nah, it was my browser being crappy, your code works perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you're trying to do with an array. Give the image something relating to a corresponding element you want to be shown (I used data attribute in example).
And give a collective class name to all the elements that are going to be shown/hidden.

Then on click, hide all and show the one related to what was clicked.

```
$('img').click(function(){
    $('.somename').hide();
    $('#div-'+$(this).data("number")).show();
});
```

See fiddle: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9emhuzw0/4/)

Comment: I'm wouldn't be too thrilled of having to supply a number value via HTML for each image. What if was working with over a hundred images?

 I just added a second broken example. I was attempting to use image array to shift through differences instead of using jquery.